# How to use same port for http and https

Tags: apache, https, port

I pretty much don't know about http and this topic, so couldn't find any answer enough to solve my question. Let me know if this question is duplicated and you already found the answer about this.

#### What I want to achieve

Normally it's working with http://domain:3000 but I want to make it accessible for https://domain:3000.

#### What I did

I installed let's encrypt and added reverse proxy settings on my apache setting file. So it was possible to access https://domain:3000 with the path such as https://domain/api but as I mentioned above I want to directly use port number on https as well.

additional lines on my httpd.conf are

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName my.domain
     ServerAlias www.my.domain *.my.domain
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.domain [OR]
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.my.domain [OR]
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.my.domain
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     Listen 443
</IfModule>
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /api http://my.domain:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://my.domain:3000
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to add more settings? or any other way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what exactly you are trying to do and what your actual issue is.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to do https for the same port. For example, make both (http://)example.com:3000 and (https://)example.com:3000 possible

Comment: Clear and simple answer: it is not possible to operate both protocols http and https on the same port by means of the http server itself.

Comment: Don't know exactly for apache httpd, but for nginx there is a solution, see https://serverfault.com/a/930789/333190

Answer (score 0):

It is better to configure the application you have to use different port for SSL connections, e.g. 3001 and forward requests via HTTPS to this port or access it directly

Comment: Is there any reason to use different port?

Comment: Because it 2 different protocols that work differently ) But it make sense if you want to use both secured and non-secured connections. If you would like to access application via secured connection only, you can have only one port for configured.